# A guaranteed way to get source-order of member fields at runtime?

Tags: java, reflection, jvm

I'm looking for a way to retrieve (at runtime) the fields of a class in source-order, so that I can perform my own "initialization processing" which is to be based on the order of declaration. I know that Javadoc for `Class.getDeclaredFields()` explicitly states that no order is guaranteed.

Some answers on SO point to `Javassist` but I can find no evidence that `javassist` has any such guarantee in the absence of line number information.

Yet this "source-order" is used by the Java compiler, as this code does not compile:

```
private int a = 10 * b;
private int b = 5;
```

Clearly, the value of `b` isn't known at the moment `a` is being declared.

This initialization order must also be present in the bytecode since at runtime the initialization must happen in the same order (granted, this is only a requirement for these edge cases :-( Yet this leads me to think that the natural thing would be to store the source order inside the `.class` file.

**Questions:**

1. How does the JVM/Byte Code go about initializing member fields in declared order, and can this information perhaps be used to reconstruct source-order of fields?
2. Is there any other guaranteed way of achieving the same. Third-party tools like Javassist are OK but it must be "guaranteed" or at least "guaranteed under specific conditions".
3. Is there any specific Java implementation that does guarantee order on `Class.getDeclaredFields()` (perhaps under specific conditions (which ones))?

For your information, I need the source order to reconstruct behavior of a legacy language where order was important. I don't like adding order explicitly e.g. by adding arrays or annotations, as I want to keep the source as readable as possible.

-- edit --
An important note may be that the fields I need to "traverse" will all be annotated, e.g. `@MyComplexType(len = 4)`. The parent class will need this meta-information to construct a kind of memory map. Yet I don't want to clutter this annotation with ordering information, as I find this hinders readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your second and third question, it is only possible to retrieve the fields in order using a kind of dirty hack:

In the bytecode, the fields of the class file are not stored in order, and neither are the methods. I don't know *why* that is the case (even though I made my own JVM compiler), but I believe the Java compiler just decides to do that. `Class.getDeclaredFields` returns the fields in the order in which they were read from the bytecode, which is why it states that no order is guaranteed.

If you still want to get them in order, I would try the following: You use a bytecode parser library such as Javassist or ASM to read the class file, and skip everything but the constructors (and the `static {}` if you also want to sort static fields). As soon as you encounter a `PUTFIELD` or `PUTSTATIC` instruction whose `owner` is the class you are inspecting, you get the current line which is available through debug information stored in the bytecode, and use it to sort the fields. The problem with this technique is its inefficiency and the fact that it relies on Line Number attributes, which are not always present in class files. Furthermore, you will only find `PUT*` instructions for fields which are explicitly initialized, default ones such as

```
protected int modifiers;
```

are not initialized by the compiler, so no instruction and thus no line number information is available in the bytecode. In this case or when there is no LineNumber attributes in general, you are unfortunately out of luck. At that point, the only solution I could come up with is to read the actual source code of the class.

Depending on the class you are trying to inspect, you might have trouble getting the actual bytecode of the class, but that is a question in and on itself.

Comment: Thanks. You mention only initialized fields have line numbers. Would it help if all fields that need to be traversed have some common annotation (see edit in the question). I expect these too have line number information that can be obtained, even if the field is not initialized? Can you elaborate on the last paragraph "you might have trouble getting the actual bytecode of the class"? I *will* need to inspect all sorts of inner and nested classes.

Comment: Depending on how much work you want to dedicate to this, you could use some annotation that doesn't take any parameters, such as `@FieldOrder` and use a custom annotation processor to convert that to `@FieldOrder(value = 0)` (`value` could have a default value that is detected by the processor, such as `-1`).

By my last paragraph I only mean that you might have problems finding the JAR file the bytecode comes from, however I believe that this is nothing compared to your actual problem.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion of Annotation Processors, sounds very interesting indeed. I have a basic processor working now. However although some of the `javax.annotation.processing` methods return `List`, the javadoc doesn't mention that these are guaranteed to be source-ordered (or I haven't found this statement yet). Also, once I have access to my annotations in source-order, how would I go about "injecting" my detected order in place of these annotations' default order value?

Comment: Update: so I did find a statement in the Javadoc of `javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement`: `Each method of this interface that returns a list of elements will return them in the order that is natural for the underlying source of program information. For example, if the underlying source of information is Java source code, then the elements will be returned in source code order.`. However this is not correct, fields are return in **alphabetical** order. Also see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300408 - it would appear this topic is haunted.

Comment: Update: alphabetical ordering is caused by (a bug/feature in) the Eclipse Java compiler, according to the above URL it is solved in Eclipse Mars (4.5). The Oracle `javac -processor ...` orders correctly. So all in all this would count as the "correct answer", except I don't see at all how to inject this information back into the class file (other than generating a completely new class). Could you please provide an example or some pointers?

Comment: I never worked with annotation processors before, therefore I don't know if annotation processors can actually *change* the semantics of a program, or if they are limited to *checking* them. However, I believe you could take a quick look at the API documentation in order to find out more about this. The Javadoc of the `javax.annotation.*` and `javax.lang.*` classes are a good start.

Comment: ***EDIT***: Turns out they only allow checking, but no modification. What you are searching for is called Aspect Oriented Programming. If you are working with Eclipse, [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) might be interesting.

Comment: I'm experimenting on generating a new class `FooOrder` for every class `Foo` containing annotations. The Order class only has one method returning the order of the fields in the "main" class. Works nicely so far. Thanks and answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

> This initialization order must also be present at runtime, for the same reason.

The order the fields are declared and the order they are initialized don't have to have anything to do with one another.  There are exceptions as you mention but this is not a requirement.

> So how does the JVM go about initializing member fields in declared order

The JVM only sets fields to their un-initialized 0, null, and false values.  Nothing else.

The only reason values have anything other than these is because there is byte code which sets each field to the value you set it to. i.e. no magic happens.

> can this information perhaps be used to reconstruct source-order of fields?

You could infer what the order might be, based on the order the fields are set in the constructor.  However, this is an assumption.  You have a better chance of assuming the order the fields appear in the class file is the order they appeared in the source.

If there is debug information, this can be used to get actual line numbers, however the JVM ignores this information.  Note: this only tells you the lines where the fields were initialised, which might not be the order they are declared.

e.g.

```
class A {
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   int d;

   A() {
      d = 1;
      //c not initialised
      b = 2;
      a = 3;
  }
```

}

So you can see the order the fields are initialised in the constructor don't match the order of declaration. In fact `c` won't be initialised at all and be left with the default `0`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Understood. I've elaborated my question a bit and asked some follow-up questions, see point 2 and 3 (you have answered my original point 1)

Comment: @geert3 The only guaranteed way to know the order the fields appear in the source, is to read the source.

Comment: @PeterLawrey not quite for non-default fields.

Comment: @Clash soft how so? Fields can be initialised in any order even if they are final.

Comment: When fields are declared with an initial value, the order of these fields is given by the bytecode instructions in the constructors that initialize these fields. See my (accepted) answer.

Comment: @Clashsoft This happens to be true, however, if just one field is not initialised this way, this won't be true and you won't know it's not true.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve information at runtime about a field or method that the compiler is not storing for you then use custom annotations.  For example,

Declare your annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface FieldOrder {
    public int order() default 0;
}
```

Annotate your fields:

```
@FieldOrder{order=1}
int field1 = 5;

@FieldOrder{order=2}
long field2 = field1 * 12;
```

Use reflection to retrieve your Field objects and the annotations on them.

```
final Class<MyClass> obj = MyClass.class;
if (obj.isAnnotationPresent(FieldOrder.class)) {
  for (final Method method : obj.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(FieldOrder.class)) {
      final Annotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(FieldOrder.class);
      final FieldOrder fieldOrder = (FieldOrder) annotation;
      final int order = fieldOrder.order();
      // do something with the field; 
      // add to sorted collection using field order?
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I know that this option exists, but I explicitly don't want to do this for sake of maintainability.

Comment: If you dont want to explicitly define the order as `value = 2`, you could change the `default` to a special value such as `-1` and detect that with a custom annotation processor. That way you can simply write `@FieldOrder int field123`, without having to worry about the numbers.